# Leaks from nowhere, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, nsmutablearray, memory-leaks

I am having real trouble with release and leaks. I have an array that just wont stop leaking! here is my code:
I have declared otherValuesArray in the .h
I have tried hundreds of different ways, including autorelease.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?? Thanks

```
otherValuesArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain]; //89% leak

NSString *tempString;
tempString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",challengeID] autorelease];
[otherValuesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithString:tempString]]; // 11% leak
tempString=nil;

tempString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",scoreMultiQuant] autorelease];
[otherValuesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithString:tempString]];
tempString=nil;

int challengeDoneTemp = [challenges otherValues:otherValuesArray];

tempString=nil;
[tempString release];

otherValuesArray = nil;
[otherValuesArray release];
```

Comment: by the way, I was getting leakes on the other `[otherValuesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithString:tempString]];` lines until I added: tempString=nil;. Also I tried changing to `otherValuesArray = [[NSMutableArray array] autorelease];` and `otherValuesArray = [NSMutableArray array];` But it crashed

Comment: Xcode is not leaking, it is just the IDE you used to write your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swap the last two lines. After setting `otherValuesArray` to nil, there is no point in sending it a release message. It is already nil, so release have no effect. So you are leaking that memory, as that is not released. Correct code will be,

```
[otherValuesArray release];   // first release
otherValuesArray = nil;   // then set to nil
```

And also `stringWithFormat` is already autoreleased. So you don't need to send it an autorelease message. You are getting a leak for it as the container `otherValuesArray` is leaking.

And also (though not related to leak) you don't need tempString at all. You can do this in one line:

```
[otherValuesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",challengeID]];
```

Comment: wow that was simple! Thats worked a treat, thanks. Ive got rid of the tempString too, and done your last tip above.

Answer (score 2):

there's a number of memory management issues, as taskinoor pointed out.

here's a simplified form of the program:

```
NSMutableArray * tmp = [NSMutableArray new];
[tmp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",challengeID]];
[tmp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",scoreMultiQuant]];
assert(challenges);
int challengeDoneTemp = [challenges otherValues:tmp];
self.otherValuesArray = tmp;
[tmp release], tmp = 0;
```

Comment: Just an addition. property otherValuesArray should be retained here and that must be released in dealloc.

Comment: @taskinoor +1 yes. even better, and if otherValuesArray is immutable: `@property (copy) NSArray * otherValuesArray;`

Comment: Thanks, Ill give that a go. Whats the benefit of using a temp array instead of just writing to the otherValuesArray? Does `self.otherValuesArray = tmp;` overwrite the data already in self.otherValuesArray? And what is the benefit of immutable? @taskinoor Also, if you dont mind explaining, can this class have a dealloc as it is a NSObject linked to UIViewController?

Comment: @Scott Walker a) you should design for concurrent execution b) using the accessor/property is the way to set it because it holds the implementation for setting the array (do not repeat yourself, or introduce a bug -- the implementation of the setter should handle the memory management, and sometimes other details) c) yes, using the property/accessor/setter should replace what the ivar points to, thus 'the data is overwritten', in a sense. `self.otherValuesArray = thing` is equal to `[self setOtherValuesArray:thing]`. the benefit of immutable is ease of maintenance, (cont)

Comment: (cont) better for concurrency, and (as a low level implementation detail) can reduce allocation count/memory usage.